# Python openpyxl telling me " No such file or directory:" even though python file is in same directory as the excel file, among others

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Beginner here.
I've tried making new excel files, running the python code while the excel file is open, tried renaming the excel file, but nothing works. I was just following this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YS6YDQKFh0&t=14s

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook("Test2.xlsx")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Name\Desktop\Python Projects\Excel Manipulation\Excel_Test.py", line 3, in <module>
    workbook = load_workbook("Test2.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1239, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test2.xlsx'
PS C:\Users\Name>**
```

Comment: It looks like your console points to `C:\Users\Name`. Is this where your Excel file is located?

Comment: Yes. The excel file is also in the same folder as the python file

Comment: To reiterate what @white said, it looks like you are running the code from `C:\Users\Name`, which will be where it is trying to find your file. If your file and script are in the same folder,  you should not be having any issues

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Turns out you just need to copy the file location, convert it to raw string, and add \ExcelFile to the end:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
location = r'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Python Projects\Excel Manipulation\Test2.xlsx'
workbook = load_workbook(location)
```

Derp.